# Group by first difference on Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Given the following data:

```
┌─id────────────┬──────────created_at─┬─state─┐
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:58:28 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:57:00 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:50:38 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:41:46 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:37:08 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:28:09 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:28:09 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:25:13 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:21:25 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:15:43 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:03:41 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 21:28:39 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 21:28:39 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 21:08:03 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 21:08:03 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:03:45 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:03:45 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:02:34 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:00:58 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:58:26 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:56:53 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:55:29 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:26:19 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:26:19 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 16:06:16 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 16:06:16 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 15:34:28 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 15:27:46 │     0 │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

I need to group the data in a way that the created_at of the first `true` state is grouped to the first `false` state. The end result should be:

```
┌─id────────────┬───────────────start─┬─────────────────end─┐
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 16:06:16 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:03:45 │ 2022-11-26 22:03:41 │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Given that, I need a way to have the data filtered in this way:

```
┌─id────────────┬──────────created_at─┬─state─┐
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 22:03:41 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:03:45 │     1 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │     0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 16:06:16 │     1 │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

So I can then apply a LEAD/LAG window function and group the values.

But I cannot find a way to group the data in that way.

I've tried several combinations of LEAD/LAG, RANK, but I could not find a way that would match the first of every event instead of the last. (First time it goes TRUE, then the following first FALSE...)

This is the closest I could get, but the results are wrong:

```
WITH states AS (
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:58:28') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:57:00') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:50:38') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:41:46') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:37:08') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:28:09') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:28:09') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:25:13') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:21:25') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:15:43') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:03:41') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:28:39') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:28:39') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:08:03') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:08:03') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:03:45') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:03:45') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:02:34') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:00:58') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:58:26') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:56:53') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:55:29') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:51:41') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:51:41') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:26:19') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:26:19') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 16:06:16') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 16:06:16') AS created_at, 1 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 15:34:28') AS created_at, 0 AS state UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567890123' AS id, toDateTime('2022-11-26 15:27:46') AS created_at, 0 AS state
)
SELECT
  id,
  created_at,
  state,
  next.1 AS next_created_at,
  next.2 AS next_state
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    created_at,
    state,
    any((created_at, state)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next
  FROM states
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
)
WHERE
  state = 1
  AND next_state = 0
```

And the result of that query:

```
┌─id────────────┬──────────created_at─┬─state─┬─────next_created_at─┬─next_state─┐
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 21:28:39 │     1 │ 2022-11-26 22:03:41 │          0 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 19:26:19 │     1 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │          0 │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fermuch , we could solve this problem using lead and case statment.

```
with states as (
----your data
),staging_data as (
select 
id,
created_at,state,
case when state = lead(state) over (partition by id order by null) then state else null end as pos 
from **states**
)
select id,created_at,state from staging_data where pos is null;
```

Comment: Is lead() a new function for clickhouse? or is it leadInFrame?

Comment: sql lead() - standard function

Comment: there is no lead() on clickhouse, and leadInFrame doesn't return the correct value. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for completion and future travelers sake.

First, let's start off by creating a test dataset:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data (
  id String,
  created_at DateTime,
  state Boolean
);


INSERT INTO data(id, created_at, state) VALUES
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:58:28'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:57:00'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:50:38'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:41:46'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:37:08'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:28:09'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:28:09'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:25:13'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:21:25'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:15:43'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 22:03:41'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:28:39'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:28:39'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:08:03'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 21:08:03'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:03:45'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:03:45'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:02:34'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 20:00:58'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:58:26'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:56:53'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:55:29'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:51:41'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:51:41'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:26:19'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 19:26:19'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 16:06:16'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 16:06:16'), 1),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 15:34:28'), 0),
  ('1234567890123', toDateTime('2022-11-26 15:27:46'), 0);
```

Now, the real query:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  created_at AS start,
  COALESCE(next_created_at, NOW()) AS end
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    max(
      if(toYear(created_at) = 1969, NULL, created_at)
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_created_at
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id,
        created_at,
        state,
        runningDifference(state) AS diff
      FROM (SELECT * FROM data)
      ORDER BY created_at ASC
    )
    WHERE (
      (state = 1 AND diff = 1) -- this means it is a start
    OR
      (state = 0 AND diff = -1) -- this means it is an end
    )
    ORDER BY created_at ASC
  )
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
)
WHERE state = 1;
```

It returns:

```
┌─id────────────┬───────────────start─┬─────────────────end─┐
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 20:03:45 │ 2022-11-26 22:03:41 │
│ 1234567890123 │ 2022-11-26 16:06:16 │ 2022-11-26 19:51:41 │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

What's the magic? All magic resides on `runningDifference(state)`. It is documented [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#runningdifferencex). Long store short, it compares current value with next value and gives the difference (delta).

I've used that difference to check when a change occurs (from state=0 to state=1 and vice-versa). Since the change to 0 to 1 is 1, and the change from 1 to 0 is -1, you can even identify which change is and activation (0 to 1) and an end (1 to 0).

Since I'm only looking for activations, I filter by `state = 1`.

The query can be compressed and made more readable, but I had weird bugs with data ordering when using `runningDifference` (since it does not work over a window, it literally scans the next row it has). That's why there are several embedded queries.